# Cortana API for Windows IoT?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, cortana

I want to use Cortana on a Raspberry Pi to answer questions and also control lights.

I looked the Cortana API docs but it seems only works to create new Cortana commands, but also I want the opposite thing: to get speech responses for user questions.

Is it possible? Were can I find code examples for that?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? I'm trying to understand what specifically you mean by "To get speech responses for user questions". Walk me through an end to end interaction, and I can probably suggest things to look at. 
Depending on what you're implementing, you may want to look at the Speech Synthesis APIs under Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis, or you might be able to use GetResponseForPrompt inside Cortana.

Comment: if my answer is correct, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cortana determines the intent of speech input and executes a function of your choice based on key words.  It is up to you to execute a function using the incoming text to formulating responses.

There are currently several open research projects around this, however nothing production to my knowledge as of today.

Project Teddy is one such project, which will be open sourced on https://github.com/drcrook1 in 2 weeks, which touches this particular problem.  Details on project teddy can be found here: http://indiedevspot.com/2015/08/21/sfl-emerging-tech-group-project-teddy-talk/

Another possible option is to use LUIS, which resides within project oxford https://www.projectoxford.ai/

As of today there is still a fair amount of code you will need to write for this type of functionality.